# bash: ./main.o: Permission denied

Tags: gcc, opencl

I built the opencl program using the commands:

```
gcc -c -I ~/AMDAPP/include main.c -o main.o
gcc main.o -o host -L ~/AMDAPP/lib/x86_64/ -l OpenCL
```

It was succesful.
When I tried to run it using `./main.o` 
i got the error message: `bash: ./main.o: Permission denied`
Can someone please tell me whats wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The executable is built to the `host` file, not the `main.o`.

`main.o` contains compiled contents of `main.c`, **not linked into an executable yet**.

Comment: Thanks for your help....                                           when I typed in the command  ./host                                  I got the error message: Failed to load kernel.  What do you think is the reason?

Comment: How could I know? This is way too less information. I need to see the code and the specific error code returned, but this is perhaps a reason to make another question.

Comment: P.S. If the answer solved your question, click the tick mark under the vote count, to mark this question as resolved.

Comment: No, this was an error message. Check what precisely returned the failing function.